# Invalid STS Request when Trying to Authenticate for SharePoint Access with REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, forms-authentication, webrequest

I'm trying to follow the instructions at the below link, but it's failing right at step 1. The response from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf is "Invalid Request". I'm copying the XML directly into Postman, updating username/password, and posting to that url, but it does not like it. Are there other things I need to set up? And to confirm, it wouldn't give this kind of error if I simply botched the username/password, right?

https://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/

**Error Response:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <psf:pp xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
            <psf:serverVersion>1</psf:serverVersion>
            <psf:authstate>0x80048800</psf:authstate>
            <psf:reqstatus>0x80045c01</psf:reqstatus>
            <psf:serverInfo ServerTime="2020-05-27T18:00:52.0727053Z">PROD-CHI-012.ProdSlices rid:83065b9d-8e7e-40a7-a3df-842141279c00</psf:serverInfo>
        </psf:pp>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <S:Fault>
            <S:Code>
                <S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value>
                <S:Subcode>
                    <S:Value>wst:InvalidRequest</S:Value>
                </S:Subcode>
            </S:Code>
            <S:Reason>
                <S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Invalid Request</S:Text>
            </S:Reason>
            <S:Detail>
                <psf:error xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
                    <psf:value>0x80045C01</psf:value>
                    <psf:internalerror>
                        <psf:code>0x80045C01</psf:code>
                        <psf:text>AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.</psf:text>
                    </psf:internalerror>
                </psf:error>
            </S:Detail>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this [demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-sharepoint-online-rest-api-via-postman-with-user-context/)

My test demo for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I didn't notice in the demo I was following that there was also an address to update. That got me one step closer but now it's acting as if the site or credentials are invalid. I note that your username includes a ".onmicrosoft.com". I don't typically login as our credentials are magically handled when I use a browser. I thought it would be my windows username or else my company email address. Any idea how to figure out what I should put there??

Comment: The account you can get from your site https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/currentuser

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me. On a browser it shows invalid feed type and Postman says access denied. Is it possible that our company has it set up so the site is only accessible via browser and no other application?

Comment: To get the account your used, login the site first and request the rest api request, not browser the rest api request directly.

Comment: I haven't been able to log in yet, but my particular issue at this stage was the lack of website in the XML. I didn't see I needed to change that. Will open new questions for further issues.